# PowerBI empty values row not displayed

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a confusing mystery...

Simple DIVIDE formula works correctly. However blank rows are not displayed.
I attempted a different method using IF, and now the blank row is correctly displayed.
However this line is only displayed if I include the IF formula (which gives a zero value I don't want).

Formula 1:

`Completion % = 
DIVIDE(SUM(Courses[Completed]),SUM(Courses[Attended]),BLANK())`

Formula 2:

`Completion %  with IF = 
IF(SUM(Courses[Attended])=0,0,DIVIDE(SUM(Courses[Completed]),SUM(Courses[Attended])))`

With only the DIVIDE formula:

[image: using only DIVIDE]

Including the IF formula:

[image]

It appears that Power BI is capable of showing this row without error, but only if I inlude the additional IF formula. I'm guessing it's because there is now a value (0) to display.

However I want to be able show all courses, including those that have no values, without the inaccurate zero value.

I don't understand why the table doesn't include these lines. Can anyone explain/help?

Comment: What is the visualyou are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is very simple, by default Power BI shows only elements for which there is at least one non-blank measure.

The [DIVIDE](https://dax.guide/DIVIDE/) operator under-the-hood execute the following:

```
IF(ISBLANK(B), BLANK(), A / B))
```

You can change its behaviour by defining the optimal parameter in order to show 0 instead of BLANK:

`DIVIDE(A, B, 0)` will be translated in the following:

```
IF(ISBLANK(B), 0, A/B))
```

### Proposed solution

Those mentioned avobe might all be possible solutions to your problem, however, my personal suggestion is to simply enable the option "[show item with no data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-show-items-no-data)" in your visualization.

Comment: I think you're missing `/B` in your last expression.

Comment: Good sir, indeed as I suspected it was an obvious answer and part of my on-going learning curve with Power BI.  The option "show values with no data" gets me exactly what I need. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While `DIVIDE(A, B, 0)` will return zero when when `B` is zero or blank, I think a blank `A` will still return a blank.

One possibility is to simply append `+0` (or prepend `0+`) to your measure so that it always returns a numeric value.

```
DIVIDE ( SUM ( Courses[Completed] ), SUM ( Courses[Attended] ) ) + 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, indeed this could be one of many possible workarounds, however would result in a false zero value rather than the desired null output. Seymour above has pointed me to the best option to resolve the problem. Many thanks.